# Cannot run the rejoin-stack.sh script

Tags: virtualbox, devstack

I got devstack today, but I've been going through a problem. Whenever I
restarted my virtualbox, I can't run the rejoin-stack.sh script. So that means I can't get into the horizon. Anyone can help me? Thank you.

PS : When I run the command rejoin-stack.sh. This message appears "Could not find. / Stack-screenrc file; stack.sh have you run yet?"

Comment: What does "I can't run" mean? Do you get errors? If so, what does the error tell you? You've provided no information that would allow anyone to try and help you. (Try calling your doctor and saying "I have a pain. It started today. How can I make it stop?" without any more information, and see if you get a diagnosis and treatment without providing any more details.)

Comment: Sorry. when I run the command rejoin-stack.sh. This message appears "Could not find. / Stack-screenrc file; stack.sh have you run yet?"

Answer (score 0):

You should run rejoin-stack.sh from the user which is used for running stack.sh

If You have used root id to run stack.sh , you should run rejoin-stack.sh as a root user.